# Why is the Pokémon Refresh button shaking?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Whenever I go into the menu, the Pokémon Refresh button wobbles and shakes to the side, even though nothing really seems out of the ordinary when I start it up. What does the shaking mean?

Answer (score 1):

The button starts shaking when you need to take care of your pokemon. Taking care of your pokemon means to:
A. Give them affection
B. Feed them
C. Play with them